# JavaFX hide task bar icon when the primary stage is closed

Tags: java, javafx, awt

I followed [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a) to create an app with tray icon. When I closed the app window, there is an icon left on the task bar. The question is how can I hide the icon on task bar when I close the window? If it is not possible, then if there is a way to bring back the window when I click the task bar icon? A cross-platform solution will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[The gist](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a) you linked to has everything you're looking for.

1. A way to reopen the JavaFX window (involves two parts):

   - [Lines 39-40](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a#file-javafxtrayiconsample-java-L39-L40):

     > ```
     > // instructs the javafx system not to exit implicitly when the last application window is shut.
     > Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
     > ```
   - [Lines 106-112](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a#file-javafxtrayiconsample-java-L106-L112):

     > ```
     > // if the user double-clicks on the tray icon, show the main app stage. 
     > trayIcon.addActionListener(event -> Platform.runLater(this::showStage));
     >
     > // if the user selects the default menu item (which includes the app name), 
     > // show the main app stage. 
     > java.awt.MenuItem openItem = new java.awt.MenuItem("hello, world"); 
     > openItem.addActionListener(event -> Platform.runLater(this::showStage));
     > ```
2. A way to exit the application completely:

   - [Lines 120-128](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a#file-javafxtrayiconsample-java-L120-L128):

     > ```
     > // to really exit the application, the user must go to the system tray icon
     > // and select the exit option, this will shutdown JavaFX and remove the
     > // tray icon (removing the tray icon will also shut down AWT).
     > java.awt.MenuItem exitItem = new java.awt.MenuItem("Exit");
     > exitItem.addActionListener(event -> {
     >     notificationTimer.cancel();
     >     Platform.exit();
     >     tray.remove(trayIcon);
     > });
     > ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But for repopening the window, I was trying to say that after closing the window, press the icon on the taskbar to reopen the window. By the way, I am not sure what OS you are using, but on macOS, the task bar icon has no effect after closing the last window.

Comment: Well, the above adds an action listener to the tray icon which should be invoked on a _double_ click. If that doesn't work across platforms (it works on Windows) then maybe using AWT is not suitable for your needs. I'm not aware of other tray icon libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I know what you mean now. The tray icon works indeed, but I'm asking for the solution of the taskbar icon.

Comment: Not having access to a Mac I can't play around with some code. Not sure I'll be able to help.